# How to update record in between 1000-2000 in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in which I have 2000 records. I update the top 1000 records using

```
Update top(1000) from table set field1=1
```

Now I want to update from 1000-2000 how can I update that I search it but didn't find any solution.

Any help will be appreciated !!!

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9497472/7505436

Comment: i want to update records in that it is selecting records..

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution it will be like this

```
Update table set field=1 where Columns_name between 1001 and 2000
```

Thanks guys