# Efficient way to page from this sql server article

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am reading about how to efficiently page through large data sets because I am not happy with `Row_Number` and `Fetch` is worst.

This is the article:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml

Now this article has this piece of code:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_PageResults_NAI] 
(
    @startRowIndex int,
    @maximumRows int
)
AS

DECLARE @first_id int, @startRow int

-- A check can be added to make sure @startRowIndex isn't > count(1)
-- from employees before doing any actual work unless it is guaranteed
-- the caller won't do that

-- Get the first employeeID for our page of records
SET ROWCOUNT @startRowIndex
SELECT @first_id = employeeID FROM employees ORDER BY employeeid

-- Now, set the row count to MaximumRows and get
-- all records >= @first_id
SET ROWCOUNT @maximumRows

SELECT e.*, d.name as DepartmentName 
FROM employees e
   INNER JOIN Departments D ON
       e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
WHERE employeeid >= @first_id
ORDER BY e.EmployeeID

SET ROWCOUNT 0

GO
```

This demo code looks OK (as with other demos you see :)). The above code works only because he is using `Order By employeeid` in `SELECT @first_id = employeeID FROM employees ORDER BY employeeid`.

Let's say I have a field named `FirstName` and want to order by that instead. How do I then write the above procedure? The above procedure obviously won't work because then we can't write `WHERE employeeid >= @first_id` because we can't get `first_id` if we order by Name. This is because `where` is executed before `order by`.

If we change the above query to:

```
Select * From (SELECT e.*, d.name as DepartmentName 
FROM employees e
   INNER JOIN Departments D ON
       e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
ORDER BY e.EmployeeID) v WHERE employeeid >= @first_id
```

then it would work but this means, the above query would give extremely poor performance on larger data sets.

So, how do we use the above demo code into production use? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have PK(or unique) on Departments.DepartmentID?

Comment: @Roman: These are not my tables. This is the demo code from http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml as stated in the question.

Comment: If they are not your tables then why do you ask "So, how do we use the above demo code into production use?"  What is the purpose of the proposed change?  It does not sort on FirstName.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best paging solution using SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747186/best-paging-solution-using-sql-server-2005)

Comment: @Blam: By above "demo code" I meant the logic that is used in the demo code and not the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question appears to be that you want to use an alternative method because `ROW_NUMBER` does not work well when sorting on non unique fields in large datasets. However the problem is that the method you want to use does not work well when sorting on non unique fields in large data sets so what can you do to correct that?

The answer is that sorting large datasets on a non unique field(s) will not perform well however you do it, unless you use indexes well.

Just to demonstrate that `ROW_NUMBER` is better than the method you have given even on the simple case of sorting on a primary key, I created the schema from your link and added following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_PagedResults_RowNumber
(
   @startRowIndex int,
   @maximumRows int
)
AS
WITH Emp AS
(   SELECT e.*, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY e.EmployeeID)
    FROM employees e
)
SELECT  TOP (@MaximumRows) 
        EmployeeID, 
        LastName, 
        FirstName, 
        e.DepartmentID, 
        Salary,
        HireDate, 
        d.Name AS DepartmentName
FROM    Emp e
        INNER JOIN Departments D ON
           e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
WHERE   rn >= @startRowIndex
ORDER BY EmployeeID;
```

I then compared the two queries:

```
EXECUTE usp_PageResults_NAI 4500, 20;
EXECUTE usp_PagedResults_RowNumber 4500, 20;
```

Firstly looking at the IO statistics, the procedure you have posted used was as follows:

```
Table 'Employees'. Scan count 1, logical reads 48
(1 row(s) affected)

(20 row(s) affected)
Table 'Departments'. Scan count 1, logical reads 41
Table 'Employees'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

*All statistics ended with `physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.` so I removed this from all of them for readability.*

The statistics when using ROW_NUMBER():

```
(20 row(s) affected)
Table 'Departments'. Scan count 1, logical reads 41
Table 'Employees'. Scan count 1, logical reads 48

(1 row(s) affected)
```

There is not much to separate the two, but ROW_NUMBER comes in slightly better with one less index scan and 2 less logical reads.

Next to look at the execution plan. Using Rowcount comes in at an estimated 84% of the query cost:

[image]

And ROW_NUMBER a measly 16%.

[image]

In terms of actual execution time, I can't draw a reasonable conclusion given the size of the data, since both execute so quickly. I can only assume the simpler plan, and lower IO make ROW_NUMBER faster too.

So rather than trying to force a square peg into a round hole and use this method of ROWCOUNT to page on a field such as FirstName, instead create an index on FirstName to assist ROW_NUMBER when doing the sort. e.g.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Employees_FirstName ON dbo.Employees (FirstName ASC) INCLUDE (DepartmentID);
```

To demonstrate the difference I ran this query:

```
SELECT  EmployeeID, 
        DepartmentID, 
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER  BY FirstName, EmployeeID)
FROM    Employees;
```

Both before adding the index:

**Before**

```
Table 'Employees'. Scan count 1, logical reads 501
```

[image]

**After**

```
Table 'Employees'. Scan count 1, logical reads 249
```

[image]

This shows the sort is able to use the index halving the number of logical reads.

Comment: I have accepted your answer because my original question doesn't have an answer itself. While this is not the answer to my question since I have already using this technique only and I have 2 million records (which will only increase over time) and it takes approximately 3 seconds to traverse from one page to another will all indexes. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried multiple different ways of SP paging, and nothing worked for me efficiently. Part of the reason is in my case SP was very complex and ran slow if I used all the criteria, conditions, sorting, filtering etc - so I couldn't afford to repeat all of them with each new page request.

The way I implemented it - I do run it with all the criteria, conditions, sorting, filtering etc. but I run it like this only once - and retrieve all the rows, but instead of getting all the columns, I retrieve just the primary key (which btw speeds up the run, comparing to all columns rereival).

In my .NET code I store that list in a `Generic List (of integer)`. Every time user request's a new page - I'd pass a list of IDs (say 50 at a time) to the SP. SP then, instead of performing full search on conditions, sorting, filtering etc. simple does an INNER JOIN to that list.

This approach turned out to be very efficient, because all the conditions - including order of records is already preserved in the list of IDs. It is flexible as well, at any time I can easily change "row-per-page" by simple supplying different number of IDs at a time.

Comment: If the search return 1 million row you download them all?   At 64 million you would hit the .NET 1 GB limit.

Comment: @Blam could you please elaborate on the math?

Comment: Then you tell how many you can cache in .NET before you hit the object size limit.   Tell me how long it take to download 1 million into cache .NET list.  And you don't even answer the question of how to sort.

Comment: @Blam Even if I used 64 *bit* IDs (which I don't) 64 *bit* makes 8 *bytes*. For 1 million records that would be less than 8Mb - a small price to pay for fast random access to any page within dataset of 1M size at pretty much no additional memory cost. Oh and if you paid a bit more attention to my post - the list of IDs will have already been sorted by initial request.

Comment: So the list is sorted.  It does not answer the question of how to created a sorted list.   Did you answer the question as to how big before you reach the 1GB .NET limit?-No  Did you answer how long it take to download 1 million?-No   The answer does not scale.

Comment: Oh never mind :) it's pointless, you live in your world, I live in a world where this is a living, breathing app. And you do not read neither answer nor comments. Oh and downvoting - good for you, you're really proving your point :))

Comment: You did not answer the stated question of how to perform the sort.  So it is a  living breathing app that does not scale.

Comment: I apologize, I must've not explained the logic clearly. Here're the steps: Step 1) Initial call to SP passes all the filtering and sorting criteria - but at this time SP returns list of PKs only - the list is sorted according to criteria. The list is stored in .NET Generic list which takes only 8Mb for 1,000,000 of records (not 1Gb).

Comment: Step 2). User requests a page of data - 50 IDs from that list are sent to the SP - instead of all the filters and sorting - list is already sorted, so joining to it will produce sorted result. SP returns back just 50 rows of data (again, not 1GB). That data is discarded when user no longer needs it (e.g. moves to another page). So data is never accumulated, never reaches 1Gb, data is sorted according to original criteria. Does this answer all the questions?

Comment: Where did I say 1 million Int32 is 1 GB?  I actually deal with large List of Int32 in .NET and with fragmentation you cannot get much past 64 million rows with the 1 GB limit.  To me that is a serious scale problem given I work with lots of tables over 200 million.  Even if it was 1 million  for sure my user does not want to wait to download 8 MB of PK to see the first page of results.  And the question is not tagged .NET.

Comment: I am sorry, I still have so much to learn about things like scalability and fragmentation, I was wrong and you were so right. *Bows to the master*. Should've know you can't replace real computer silence with some custom hacks.

Comment: Not necessarily a hack.  I use it some times but never for more than 10,000 PK.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, however I am a bit concerned about your approach since I have 2 million rows and they would only keep increasing over months. Thanks anyways.