# Pagination of records with MSSQL 2005

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to paginate the records fetched into pages of 10 (using PHP AJAX on MSSQL Server 2005). (I am passing SQL as PHP strings to MSSQL server)
I wish to display button for each page (for example if there are 45 records then I wish to display 5 buttons with each button fetching 10 records).
I have came across this code-

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OrderDate ) AS RowNum, *
          FROM      Orders
          WHERE     OrderDate >= '1980-01-01'
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= 1
    AND RowNum <= 10
ORDER BY RowNum
```

But  this is highly ineffective because firstly whole database is fetched then from it 10 rows is fetched every time.
Could anyone suggest some technique (that works with MSSQL server 2005) wihich fetches only 10 rows at a time and not the whole 100 records at a time.
The above method also includes an extra column (it requires a primary key). I wish to get rid of that column too!

Also, since I have to display the page numbers (pagination tabs), I wish to have a count of total number of records beforehand.

Thanks!

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3747186/314291). Joe's link [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/) looks at performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use LINQ. Very efficient.

**Edit**
Well then.

```
SELECT * 
FROM etc
WHERE Row_Number() BETWEEN '".$startLimit."' AND '".$endLimit."'
```

Might work for you. Remember to escape the variables so no dangerous code can bass by.

Comment: LINQ extends capability of C# and Visual Basic. But I am using PHP. Let me know if I am mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I have done til now. But this is not efficient. suppose there are 100 records then using this method, we extract all 100 of them and then take a range out of them.

Comment: Try and use SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ....... Should only select 10, then customize it.